# how to input get focus every time in react navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I use react navigation TabNavigator and I want every time user goes to second tab, one TextInput in screen get focus and keyboard gets popup

Answer (score 2):

You can use [refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) and [react navigation lifecycle](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-prop.html#addlistener-subscribe-to-updates-to-navigation-lifecycle) for this:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.input = React.createRef();
  this.didFocusDSubscription = this.props.navigation.addListener(
    'didFocus',
    payload => {
      this.input.current.focus();
    }
  );
}
render() {
  return <TextInput ref={this.input} />;
}
```

Comment: current is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

this might help you

```
this.viewDidAppearListener = this.props.navigation.addListener('didFocus', (payload) => this._viewDidAppear(payload));
```

`didFocus` event will be triggered every time the view is showed (like `viewDidAppear` in iOS) so you can then do `focus()` on your textinput manually.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest is to add "autoFocus" to your textInput
Like this:

```
 <TextInput 
       placeholder="Type any activity name"
       placeholderTextColor="lightgray"
       ...
       ref="textInput"
       autoFocus />
```

Comment: aitoFocus get focus for first time and second time not work

Answer (score 0):

For react-navigation@3.X.X use *navigation.addListener* and *.focus()*:

```sh
class AutoFocusedTextInput extends React.Component {
  state = {
    text: '',
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.navigation.addListener('didFocus', payload => {this.textInput.focus()})
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    didFocusSubscription.remove();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <TextInput
          ref={(component) => this.textInput = component}
          autoFocus={true}
          placeholder="Start typing"
          onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({text})}
          value={this.state.text}
        />
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

The reference:
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/3.x/navigation-prop#addlistener---subscribe-to-updates-to-navigation-lifecycle